# Doubt regarding the proof of a proposition (Tom Dieck 2.3)1

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Let $K \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a compact convex subset with non-empty interior $K^\circ$. Then there exists homeomorphism pairs $(D^n,S^{n-1}) \rightarrow (K, \partial K)$which sends $0 \in D^n$ to a preassigned $x \in K^\circ$

It is proved using the following claim:

> A ray from $0$ intersects the boundary $\partial K$ at exactly one point

Consider the set $[1,2]$ then a ray from $0 \to 1$ can be extended to also intersect at $2$ that is $0 \to 2$ is $\lambda x$ for the ray $x$ from $0$ to $1$ to overcome this we would need the ball of radius $1$ centered at $0$ (denoted by $B(0,1) \subset K$

My question is the extra assumption implied by something in the statement(s) or is this a valid counterexample?
I was thinking along the lines of $0 \in K^\circ$ but if I have the set K to contain only $B(0, \tfrac{1}{2})$ then the extra assumption is not assumed(?) does this have to do with convexity of K?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think they're simply identifying the element $0 \in D^n$ with $x \in K^\circ$. So what it should say is "A ray from $x$ intersects the boundary $\partial K$ at exactly one point". Then your counterexample is not valid, since we need to choose $x \in K^\circ$, but you chose $0 \notin (1,2)=K^\circ$.

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: So I must choose a point in K to be 0 and then for any ball of radius being a real number this would work?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to show? That there exists an interval with some point in it, such that some ray starting at that point intersects the boundary more than once? I'm not sure what you mean by "this"...

Comment: sorry I should have made my comment more explicit by 'this' I meant that in my second(?) paragraph I write to overcome the problem faced we must have $B(0,1) \subset K$ but instead of the radius being $1$ can any radius work?

Comment: to Dieck writes "Let $K \subset \mathbb R^n$ be closed and compact and $0 \in K^\circ$." This is a special case. If we consider a general $x  \in K^\circ$, we should shift $K$ via a translation $T$ on $\mathbb R^n$ to $K' = T(K)$ such that $T(x) = 0$.